# Phing, call a command get its output into a property

Tags: php, phing

I have a script that can lookup and output or write my current release # to a text file. Now the only problem is how do I get this version number into a PHING property.

Right now my PHING target builds build.zip and built.tar, I would like it to build build-1.0.0.zip or whatever the version script decides the current version is. How can I do this? Will I have to create my own "task"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need to create your own task for this. The task may look something like...

```
<?php
require_once "phing/Task.php";

class VersionNumberTask extends Task
{
    private $versionprop;

    public function setVersionProp($versionprop)
    {
        $this->versionprop = $versionprop;
    }

    public function init()
    {
    }

    public function main()
    {
        // read the version text file in to a variable
        $version = file_get_contents("version.txt");
        $this->project->setProperty($this->versionprop, $version);
    }
}
```

Then you would define the task in your build xml

```
<taskdef classname="VersionNumberTask" name="versiontask" />
```

Then call the task

```
<target name="dist">
    <versiontask versionprop="version.number"/>
</target>
```

At this point, you should be able to access the version number using ${version.number} throughout your build xml.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

An alternative approach is to use the `outputProperty` attribute on the ExecTask to provide a property in your build file.

```
<target name="version">
  <exec command="cat version.txt" outputProperty="version.number" />
  <echo msg="Version: ${version.number}" />
</target>
```

[More information](http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/300)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach that works on both Windows and Linux.

```
<exec executable="php" outputProperty="version.number">
    <arg value="-r" />
    <arg value="$fh=file('version.txt'); echo trim(array_pop($fh));" />
</exec>
<echo msg="Current version is: ${version.number}"/>
```

Assumes the last line of the file is simply the version number, and if you would like to update the version number in the file. Try this.

```
<propertyprompt propertyName="release_version" defaultValue="${version.numver}" promptText="Enter version to be released."/>
<exec executable="php">
    <arg value="-r" />
    <arg value="$file=file_get_contents('version.txt'); $file = str_replace('${version.number}', '${release_version}', $file); file_put_contents('version.txt', $file);" />
</exec>
<echo msg="Version number updated." />
<property name="version.number" value="${release_version}" override="true" />
```

Comment: Copied from the CakePHP build script.

Answer (score 1):

Also alternative and best way (my opinion) that works on both Windows and Linux it is use native task `LoadFileTask`

```
<loadfile property="myVersion" file="version.txt" />
<echo msg="Current version is: ${myVersion}"/>
```

also you can use `filterchain`

```
<loadfile property="myVersion" file="version.txt">
    <filterchain><striplinebreaks /></filterchain>
</loadfile>
<echo msg="Current version is: ${myVersion}"/>
```

[More information](http://www.phing.info/docs/master/webhelp/LoadFileTask.html)